# Getting Started with JNI and C under Windows

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jni4net, jnienv

I'm new in Java learning and first time want to get start JNI. And I am working with Cygwin and I have created a file with .java (Helloworld.java) extension as follows:

```
class HelloWorld {
     private native void print();
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new HelloWorld().print();
     }
     static {
         System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
     }
 }
```

Then I compile the file through the command line (`javac Helloworld.java`) after that create a native header file through command `javah –jni Helloworld`
Then also implement by creating a C file as:

```
#include <jni.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "HelloWorld.h"

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
 Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     printf("Hello World!\n");
     return;
 }
```

After that while  I run the command

```
 Gcc –wall –g Helloworld.c –o hello
```

Give the message in command prompt line in Cygwin

```
 helloworld.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.
```

How to run and what is the procedure to set the path to execute the file? Please help me any one. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you either didn't install JNI library for C or you didn't include it in the include path.

Comment: IMHO, JNI is the worst possible thing you could have picked up given that you are new to Java. I'd personally recommend starting with the [Java Learning Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) and grab a good book like Head First Java.

Comment: Why is this tagged with jni4net?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you haven't added the jni directory to the include directory list, check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/is/vclanguage/thread/cd7f2d1d-f750-494c-a3b2-7d4186cfe51c for details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you installed a JDK, you need to inform gcc about the includes directory for JNI:

```
-I$JAVA_HOME/../include
```

where `$JAVA_HOME` should be set as the parent directory of the Java `bin` directory (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre` on my machine, for example). If it is not set, well, it is simpler if you just locate the folder where your `jni.h` header resides.

I agree that to start learning Java from JNI is a daunting task, but I respect your decision. If you fashion books, I would suggest [Core Java Volume I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354764) and [Core Java Volume II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354799). At the end of the latter, in particular, you can find a pretty exhaustive coverage of native methods.

Answer (score 1):

I used MinGW on Windows.  After adding ";C:\MinGW\bin\" to the Path Environment variable, I was able to run gcc.exe from the Windows command prompt using the command below.

The jni.h file is located in java home include folder.  You can use the JAVA_HOME environment variable or specify explicitly.

```
 gcc -c -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include\win32" "S:\Accessibility\tools\src\test\java\com\accessibility\HelloWorld.c"
```

This created a HelloWorld.o file.

Answer (score 0):

If Visual Studio Successfully installed on your machine, You can **compile** using **visual studio developer command prompt**.

To produce **X86 (32 bit)** version dll use 
"VS20XX x86 Native Tools Command Prompt"

To produce **X64 (64 bit)** version dll use 
"VS20XX x64 Native Tools Command Prompt"

*XX* in *VS20XX* is visual studio version 2008 and above.

```
cl.exe /LD /EHsc /I "%JAVA_HOME%\include" /I "%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" TestJNIString.c
```

Note: Make sure JAVA_HOME variable is set in environment variable.