# PocketSphinx for Windows desktop in Java

Tags: desktop, pocketsphinx

I downloaded the library files (`.dll`) to make PocketSphinx work for Windows desktop. From the command prompt it is working. I want to use these dlls in a Java application so that I can create a `.jar` and use it as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use pocketsphinx.dll in java. You have to compile JNI extension in a special way as explained in:

[Getting Started with JNI and C under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154020/getting-started-with-jni-and-c-under-windows)

pocketsphinx already supports [SWIG](http://swig.org), so you can create the wrapper automatically from `pocketsphinx.i` interface description. However, you need to compile everything into dll file after that yourself. You can collect sources and just write another makefile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply **Nikolay**. I am able to create wrapper. But my question was how to create a `.jar` out of it.

Comment: I am able to regenerate .dll after adding c wrapper files. but when i am loading those .dll then getting following error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: E:\Workspace\Desktop\TestPocketSphinx\lib\pocketsphinx_jni.dll:*The specified procedure could not be found*
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary
    at test.DecoderTest.<clinit>(DecoderTest.java:26)

Comment: It is hard to help, you can provide the whole test package in archive. Upload it somewhere  (dropbox for example) and give here a link.

Comment: Library is up and working. But now I am stuck at some other place. If we execute pocketsphinx_continuous.exe from command line we have to use **-inmic** attribute to use microphone. How Can achieve same thing by using java??

Comment: You record audio from java as data (Microphone class on javax.sound API) and pass it to the recognizer.

Comment: I am able to run DecoderTest.java perfectly. But i want to achieve same thing with microphone means my microphone is continuously recording and i am sending the audioInputStream data to **decoder.processRaw** before even stopping microphone. I tried this but somehow. .dll library is not returning any logs and **decoder.hyp()** is also coming as null. continuously. I think that recorder thread is messing with the decoder library thread. in C library

Comment: Unlikely. It is the issue with your java code. In case you want help on this you can post another question and provide all code you have.

Comment: please review this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084097/continous-keyphrase-detection-in-pocketsphinx-for-windows-desktop-using-java