# Sending data to PocketSphinx for Windows desktop in Java

Tags: java, desktop, pocketsphinx

Here is my thread function

```
public void run() {
        recorder.start();
        d.startUtt();
        d.setRawdataSize(300000);
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];

        // Skip the first buffer, usually zeroes
        recorder.read(b, 0, b.length);
        while ((!interrupted()))
        {
            int nbytes;
            short[] s = null;
            nbytes = recorder.read(b, 0, b.length);

            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b, 0, nbytes);
            s = new short[nbytes/2];
            bb.asShortBuffer().get(s);
            d.processRaw(s, nbytes/2, false, false);

            if (nbytes > 0)
            {
                d.processRaw(s, nbytes, false, false);

                Hypothesis hypothesis = d.hyp();

                if(hypothesis != null)
                    System.out.println(hypothesis.getHypstr());
            }
            if (this.timeoutSamples != -1) {
                this.remainingSamples -= nbytes;
            }
        }
        recorder.stopRecording();
        d.endUtt();
    }
```

In this my microphone is continuously recording and i am sending the audioInputStream data to decoder.processRaw before even stopping microphone. I tried this but somehow. .dll library is not returning any logs and decoder.hyp() is also coming as null. continuously. I think that recorder thread is messing with the decoder library thread. in C library.

EDIT: initialization of decoder

```
 Config c = Decoder.defaultConfig();
    String acousticModelLoc = "speech\\model\\en-us-ptm";
    String dictLoc = "dictionary\\cmudict-en-us.dict";

    String kwFileLoc = "speech\\grammar\\digits.gram";


    c.setString("-hmm", acousticModelLoc);
    c.setString("-jsgf", kwFileLoc);
    c.setString("-dict", dictLoc);
    d = new Decoder(c);
```

PLEASE help

Comment: You need to show how do you initialize the decoder. You also need to add `-rawlogdir <dir>` to store raw audio logs.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev please review edit

Comment: You need to share relevant data files, you need to store log into a file and share it too

Comment: Can you please tell what all data files you need?

Comment: raw audio logs, digits.gram

Comment: Audio logs : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ns9bfvwie11q9qt/000000000.raw?dl=0                   Digits.gram : https://github.com/Ayushgupta25/opensource/blob/master/digits.gram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
 d.processRaw(s, nbytes, false, false);
```

is offensive, you send the data twice and you send the wrong size of the data. You need to remove it since you already send data for processing before.

```
        d.processRaw(s, nbytes/2, false, false);
        if (nbytes > 0)
        {
    ->>>>>  d.processRaw(s, nbytes, false, false);

            Hypothesis hypothesis = d.hyp();

            if(hypothesis != null)
                System.out.println(hypothesis.getHypstr());
        }
```

You can open rawdata in audacity and listen, it should be clean speech. In your case it is corrupted since you do not send data properly to the decoder.

Comment: Is there any specific audio format which we have to follow??

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "follow". The audio is 16khz 16bit mono.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nikolay I am able to get results now. I guess one last step is remaining. When speech detection starts, once it detects something hypothesis didn't change even if i am speaking continuously something else. means according to my grammar. if i say, **pick twenty two** first i get the correct hypothesis now without stopping anything if i change my statement **pick eighty five** then it is still printing the old hypothesis only.. It should get updated as i say right??

Comment: You need to end utterance when d.endUtt when word is detected and start it again with d.startUtt.

Comment: please review this link. I need your help ASAP.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231510/pocketsphinx-for-windowsphone-setsearch-function-in-speechrecognizer-is-throwi]